# Valgrind results of a "segmentation fault" program

Tags: c++, valgrind

My program (./a.out) encountered with a segmentation fault, so I use Valgrind to check if I can find at which line of code the program corrupts. I got the following output, but I cannot understand them. To me, the most suspicious line of the output is **==17967==  Address 0x20687cf80 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 16 alloc'd**, does this line means the address 0x20687cf80 is not propoerly allocated a memory block? What can I do to resolve this problem.

I am using a 64-bit linux with 64GB ram.

```
[root@gpu BloomFilterAndHashTable]# valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full ./a.out /mnt/disk2/experiments/two_stage_bloom_filter/test/10_10.txt /mnt/disk2/experiments/10M_worstcase_trace/w_10_10.trace 24
==17967== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==17967== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==17967== Using Valgrind-3.6.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==17967== Command: ./a.out /mnt/disk2/experiments/two_stage_bloom_filter/test/10_10.txt /mnt/disk2/experiments/10M_worstcase_trace/w_10_10.trace 24
==17967==
9998797 Prefixes loaded!  //output of my program
==17967== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x4201a040, 0x6f423220) (defined)
==17967== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x9c834040, 0x20687cf40) (undefined)
insertion cost time(us): 173168519      9998797 17.318935       0.057740 //output of my program
==17967== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x23647d040, 0x25647d040) (defined)
Trace loaded! //output of my program
lookup cost time(us): 5728767367        67108864        85.365286       0.011714  //output of my program
==17967== Mismatched free() / delete / delete []
==17967==    at 0x4A055FE: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:366)
==17967==    by 0x401B13: hash_table_delete(BloomFilter*, char*) (BloomFilterAndHashTable.cpp:503)
==17967==    by 0x402212: main (BloomFilterAndHashTable.cpp:687)
==17967==  Address 0x20687cf80 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 16 alloc'd
==17967==    at 0x4A05F97: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:261)
==17967==    by 0x40146D: hash_table_insert(char*, int, BloomFilter*) (BloomFilterAndHashTable.cpp:293)
==17967==    by 0x401DD5: main (BloomFilterAndHashTable.cpp:597)
==17967==
Delete succeeded!  //output of my program
deletion cost time(us): 178048113       9998797 17.806953       0.056158  //output of my program
==17967== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x23647d030, 0x25647d050) (noaccess)
--17967:0:aspacem  Valgrind: FATAL: VG_N_SEGMENTS is too low.
--17967:0:aspacem    Increase it and rebuild.  Exiting now.
[root@gpu BloomFilterAndHashTable]#
```

Comment: `Mismatched free() / delete / delete []` Have you allocated an array with ``new ...[]`` and are trying to delete it with a simple `delete`? Or viceversa...

Comment: why not start with gdb to know where the segmentation fault occurred.Its much easier to use gdb

Comment: You might need to check what you do on lines 283 and 503 in file `BloomFilterAndHashTable.cpp`.

Comment: @Adri C.S. does this mean I use new/malloc and delete/free promiscuously? Yes, I do allocated an array with `new` and delete it with `delete`.

Comment: @Pradheep yes, I should have a try with gdb.

Comment: You should not mix `new[]` and `delete` or `new` and `delete[]` or `malloc` and `delete` and so on. As stated [here](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.rudefn), in Linux it seems not to matter, but in other platforms this might crash. Also, check the part @JoachimPileborg and @ArneMertz told you.

Comment: @Adri C.S. thank you very much, you point out the problem and I have found the mismatch.

Comment: @Pradheep, one more question, can gdb be used to debug multi-thread programing with OpenMP?

Comment: My pleasure! And yes, you should be able to debug multithread apps with `gdb`. For example, when you reach a breakpoint you can type `info threads`. There you will see the number of threads running and switch between them to check what they're doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "suspicious" output **==17967== Address 0x20687cf80 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 16 alloc'd** means, that there is an allocated block of memory, 16 bytes in size. Address 0x20687cf80 is the address of the very first byte of that block (i.e. it's the address of the whole block). So the line itself does only tell you details about a memory block that is involved in the whole warning.

The warning itself is about a "mismatched free()". The following lines show where the `free` was called:

> ==17967==    at 0x4A055FE: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:366)
>   ==17967==    **by 0x401B13: hash_table_delete(BloomFilter*, char*)** (BloomFilterAndHashTable.cpp:503)

Meaning, `hash_table_delete` calls `free()`. Now, why does valgrind think that this is a mismatch? Because the address of the memory block that gets freed (0x20687cf80) was allocated by `operator new`, which was called by `hash_table_insert`:

> ==17967==    at 0x4A05F97: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:261)
>   ==17967==    **by 0x40146D: hash_table_insert(char*, int, BloomFilter*)** (BloomFilterAndHashTable.cpp:293)

This is suspicious. If it is the source of your error is another problem, but you should fix it anyways.

Comment: Thank you for so detailed analysis! I will fix this problem.